# 3 phase BLDC sinusoidal drive using PWM controller and/or DSP?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, three-phase, dsp, motor-controller, speed

My background is mechanical engineering (robotics). I apologize in advance.

I have a sensitive torque ripple (Vibrations) application and would like to use sinusoidal drive to run a 3 phase BLDC motor instead of trapezoidal for low speeds. This is for a speed controller (just inferring torque).

12V motors, 8W peak, estimated 2W Steady state. Unfortunately, I am forced to use the UC1825 pwm controller chip. Can the UC1825 PWM controller output to 6 mosfets (inverter) portion, whereupon it has 3 phase output and 1 for direction?What are comparable sinusoidal drive chips?

Datasheet, UC1825: http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=uc1825&fileType=pdf

Alos, if I could implement this using DSP inside an fpga, would I still need a pwm controller (UC1825) or just an 3-phase inverter ?

Thanks!

Comment: From personal experience - buy a ready made all-in-one BLDC controller. You will end up with it anyway after a significant time struggling with homebrew ones...

Comment: "Unfortunately, I am forced to use the UC1825 pwm controller chip". This is nonsense. Make an investigation around FOC - Field Orientated Control with PMSM. BLDC isn't even the right choice for your problem and forget the UC1825, there's nothing you can do with it.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Jack, I will check out your link tonight. The UC1825 has outputs for 3 phases? Why can I not drive the 3phase BLDC?    Also, if a dsp generates the sinusoidal wave, can I use 3 half bridges as an inverter and avoid the UC1825?

Comment: @user165514 Because, different things are designed for different uses and if its too specialized you can't use it for something else. Just because a cement mixing truck is a truck with 4 wheels doesn't mean it can be used as a general purpose truck. Too specialized. Read the first sentence of the datasheet and look at the highly specialized inputs on the block diagram which are irrelevant for a motor.

Comment: If using a DSP or FPGA, you would need to add gate drivers add transistor switches and a feedback mechanism. But it is not as simple as it sounds but informative. Expect to basically forget your original project for some time while building this one.

Answer (score 2):

A single UC1825 is not capable of driving a 3 phase motor. 
You could perhaps build a controller with 3 * UC1825, with one for each phase of the BLDC. However the complexity of using such an solution would seem hardly worth the efforts.

I'd suggest you read this great [application note from TI](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa503/slaa503.pdf) using an MSP430 to generate the PWM signals as a starting point.
How you proceed will depend on whether you have Hall Effect sensors on your current motors, or are constrained to build a sensorless driver solution.

You would definitely be better purchasing a BLDC integrated servo to simplify your task.
I'd recommend you look at [Teknic's Clearpath-SDSK servo](https://www.teknic.com/products/clearpath-brushless-dc-servo-motors/clearpath-sd/) as a potential plug in replacement for your BLDC motors. This gives you a simple Step/Dir interface and would relieve you of much work designing your own solution.